# Three.js the canvas inside the tabs are not inhered the full width and height of the parent element

Tags: canvas, tabs, three.js, resize

I use the Three.js canvas inside a tab container but for some unknown reason, the 3D viewport is not inhered the full width & height of the parent element.

@description

I have 2 tabs the first tab is active in the second tab is where I have the 3D  viewport (canvas).

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">
      <div id="canvas3D"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/usxp6tdt/25/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(VW) unit on CSS code I just say the parent width to be

#canvas3D {

width: calc(100vw - 60px);
height: calc(100vh - 60px);

}

I hope someone is gonna helped :)